# cefpython get and exe and need to run with admin on win7 otherwise it will fail and say msvcr90.dll error

Tags: cefpython

I have add the need files to compile folder such as

```
def get_cefpython_path():
    from cefpython3 import cefpython
    path = os.path.dirname(cefpython.__file__)
    return "%s%s" % (path, os.sep)

def get_data_file():
    cefp = get_cefpython_path()
    data_files = [('', ['%s/icudt.dll' % cefp,
                    '%s/d3dcompiler_43.dll' % cefp,
                    '%s/devtools_resources.pak' % cefp,
                    '%s/ffmpegsumo.dll' % cefp,
                    '%s/libEGL.dll' % cefp,
                    '%s/libGLESv2.dll' % cefp]),
                    #'%s/Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest' % cefp,
                    #'%s/msvcm90.dll' % cefp,
                    #'%s/msvcp90.dll' % cefp,
                    #'%s/msvcr90.dll' % cefp]),
                    ('locales', ['%s/locales/en-US.pak' % cefp]),
                    ]
    return data_files
```

I node the Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest, msvcm90.dll, msvcp90.dll, msvdr90.dll for in path cefp there are other needed files but no these ones.I even tried to copy all files in path C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3 to my build folder.
Finally I run the exe on win7 fail and show msvcr90.dll error but when I run it with admin it is ok.
Please help me and told me why

Comment: "libcef.dll" file seems to be missing. Make sure you are including all binary files (*.pak, *.dll).

Comment: I am sure I have include all binary files. The final exe can execute on my own computer.On another computer,win7 it can execute with admin but msvcr90.dll error without admin.

Comment: Now the situation is that I build an desktop application and install it in C:/Program files.It can not run without admin and say MSVCR90.DLL error.But when I install it in C:/Program files (x86) it would be ok and run very well. Can you help me?How to make it run when install it in C:/Program files? I have tried that in py2exe setup options add "dll_excludes":[MSVCR90.DLL] and it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much.This problem have been fixed throuth this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cefpython/R9mNoP8r8wI/ifsE-d1IBQAJ.Details can see the url above.